# Setting a custom height for a view with a CenterX constraint

Tags: ios, swift

I have a child view being programmatically being presented by its parent view. I want to set the CenterXAnchor for the child view to be constrained to the parent's CenterXAnchor, but I want the child view to have a specific height and width.

```
childViewController.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    parentViewController.view.centerXAnchor)
```

How do I go about doing this?

I have tried setting a frame for the childViewController but that messes with the anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

Given below is an example showing how to do the following:

- Add a child view controller
- Setup constraints (layout anchors) for the child view

## Code

```
private func showChildView() {

    let childViewController = UIViewController()
    let parentViewController = self

    childViewController.view.backgroundColor = .brown


    parentViewController.addChildViewController(childViewController)

    let parentView = parentViewController.view!
    let childView = childViewController.view!

    //For programatically created view set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    parentView.addSubview(childView)

    childView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    childView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    childView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    childView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: parentViewController)
}
```

## Further reading:

- Please read about AutoLayout. Refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/
- When you use the autolayout you must not set the frame directly.
- Autolayout is like a set of rules / constraints, so the frame would be determined based on the rules you set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Height and Width Anchor to set it to a certain height/width. It can also be relative height to another view.

In your example:

```
childViewController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
childViewController.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
```

EDIT: Also remember to use '.isActive = true' to activate the constraint.

This makes your view a height and width of 50.

You can read more on it here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622590-heightanchor
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622605-widthanchor

Answer (score 0):

**Please Refer sample code**

```
    //Intiallising Child ViewController
    let controller = UIViewController()
    controller.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
    controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    addChildViewController(controller)
    controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    view.addSubview(controller.view)



    //Setting Constrains programattically
    controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.view, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 150)

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 150)

    let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.view, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.view, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([widthConstraint, heightConstraint, xConstraint, yConstraint])**strong text**
```

**Sample output**
[image]